# Single swap on a string

Tags: python, string, algorithm, bioinformatics

I need to find a faster way to find the swaps in a 8-11 character string, in the following manner:

Given a string `'STDILGNLYE'`, find all the single letter swaps for the letters:

```
list_AA = ['A', 'R', 'N', 'D', 'C', 'Q', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'L', 'K', 'M',
           'F', 'P', 'S', 'T', 'W', 'Y', 'V']
```

i.e, for each letter in the string, substitute each letter in the original string with one in `list_aa`. The output would be:

```
ATDILGNLYE
RTDILGNLYE
NTDILGNLYE
...
SADILGNLYE
SRDILGNLYE
SNDILGNLYE
...
...
STDILGNLYV
```

For a total of 200 new strings (20 swaps per each position in the string).
What I have so far:

```
def _create_swaps(original_str):
    list_peps = []
    for i in range(len(original_str)):
        for k in range(len(list_AA)):
            list_peps.append(_insert_aa(original_str, i, list_aa[k]))

    #remove original string
    return [i for i in list_peps if i != original_str]


def _insert_aa(string, index, aa):
    list_string_elements = list(string)
    del list_string_elements[index]
    hash_string.insert(index, aa)
    return "".join(hash_string)
```

Since this needs to be repeated ~10**6 times, it is the slowest step in a larger project. Is there a way of finding such swaps in a faster manner (by eliminating the `"".join`, insert, steps/ by finding swaps on the fly)?

For reference:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
185275200  330.286    0.000  429.295    0.000 models.py:233(_insert_aa)
975240     147.322    0.000  616.979    0.001 models.py:225(_create_swaps)
185280201/185280197   59.137    0.000   59.138    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
185275208  39.875    0.000   39.875    0.000 {method 'insert' of 'list' objects}
975240     21.027    0.000   21.027    0.000 models.py:231(<listcomp>)
186746064  18.516    0.000   18.516    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
```

Comment: Do you need to emit all the generated strings, or just count them?

Comment: @Steve I need all the strings. As you can see from the return call from `_create_swaps`, it returns all created strings except the original one.

Comment: You may want to try to figure out a way get replace one of the operations with a `map()`...see [this article](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/) on loop efficiency...of course profiling is always better than theory though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is is a cleaner version of what you're looking for, even though you've already selected an answer (it's not the most pythonic).

You shouldn't ever use range to get the index of an iterable, you should use enumerate if you want to be pythonic about it.

```
>>> def swaps(s, lst):
...   for index, _ in enumerate(s):
...     for letter in lst:
...       temp = list(s)
...       temp[index] = letter
...       yield ''.join(temp)
...
>>> list_AA = ['A', 'R', 'N', 'D', 'C', 'Q', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'L', 'K', 'M', 'F', 'P', 'S', 'T', 'W', 'Y', 'V']
>>> s = 'STDILGNLYE'
>>>
>>> for _ in swaps(s, list_AA):
...   print _
...
ATDILGNLYE
RTDILGNLYE
NTDILGNLYE
..........
GTDILGNLYE
HTDILGNLYE
ITDILGNLYE
```

Also, a simplistic approach in python3:

```
>>> def swaps(s, lst):
...   for i, _ in enumerate(s):
...     yield from ['%s%s%s' % (s[:i], x, s[i+1:]) for x in lst]
...
>>> swaps(s,list_AA)
<generator object swaps at 0x10c9205c8>
>>> a=_
>>> next(a)
'ATDILGNLYE'
>>> next(a)
'RTDILGNLYE'
>>> next(a)
'NTDILGNLYE'
>>> next(a)
'DTDILGNLYE'
```

---

*edit: compromising solution on speed/readability*

```
def swap3(s, lst):
    for i, _ in enumerate(s):
        head, tail = s[:i], s[i+1:]
        yield from ['%s%s%s'%(head,c,tail) for c in lst]
```

---

And heres a benchmark test of all three:

```
s='STDILGNLYE'
list_AA=['A', 'R', 'N', 'D', 'C', 'Q', 'E', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'L', 'K', 'M', 'F',
        'P', 'S', 'T', 'W', 'Y', 'V']

# the correct sample size
list_new = list_AA * (10**6 // len(list_AA))

def swaps0(string, replacements):
    for i in range(len(string)):
        head = string[:i]
        tail = string[i+1:]
        for letter in replacements:
            yield head + letter + tail

def swaps1(s, lst):
  for i, _ in enumerate(s):
    yield from ['%s%s%s' % (s[:i], x, s[i+1:]) for x in lst]

def swaps2(s, lst):
  for index, _ in enumerate(s):
    for letter in lst:
      temp = list(s)
      temp[index] = letter
      yield ''.join(temp)

timeit [_ for _ in swaps0(s, list_new)]
timeit [_ for _ in swaps1(s, list_new)]
timeit [_ for _ in swaps2(s, list_new)]


In [9]: timeit [_ for _ in swaps0(s, list_new)]
1 loop, best of 3: 2.61 s per loop
In [10]: timeit [_ for _ in swaps1(s, list_new)]
1 loop, best of 3: 6.57 s per loop
In [11]: timeit [_ for _ in swaps2(s, list_new)]
1 loop, best of 3: 8.61 s per loop
```

Is it worth it? I'd say it depends on how much larger you expect this sample size to grow and how often you're going to run the code.

If the code isn't going to be running frequently (say, hundreds of times per hour) and the sample sample size isn't going to grow exponentially (to the order of 10**50 or 10**100) then I'd say go for readability.

If this is going to be computed extremely often with increasing sample size, go for performance.

Finally, we're left with a compromising solution combining enumerate with the head/tail splitting:

```
def swap3(s, lst):
    for i, _ in enumerate(s):
        head, tail = s[:i], s[i+1:]
        yield from ['%s%s%s'%(head,c,tail) for c in lst]

In [16]: timeit [_ for _ in swap3(s, list_new)]
1 loop, best of 3: 3.99 s per loop
```

Comment: I do like the enumerate idea.  However, slicing and concatenation is faster.
timeit variants = [v for v in generate_all_variants(s, list_AA)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 34.3 µs per loop

timeit variants = [v for v in swaps(s, list_AA)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 271 µs per loop

Comment: @steve I updated my answer with a more simplistic approach using Python3

Comment: Also, the 'zen' of python is that simplistic, readable code is better than ugly code that has micro-optimizations.  The optimization is just that, a micro-optimization. You'd need to be replacing a very large number of characters for it to be significantly faster.

Comment: @CharlesAddis in fact for this specific purpose a micro-optimization would be preferred as I'll be performing swaps on a huge number of strings, as I've noted. It's the largest bottleneck in my code. Thanks for the input regardless, I've learned a thing or two from your answer.

Comment: @CarloMazzaferro 10^6 is not really "a large number of times" for a computer... think 10**100

Comment: @CarloMazzaferro updated the answer with your exact sample size and the bench marks.

Comment: @CarloMazzaferro I've also updated a compromising solution (from python3) that uses techniques found in both answers to provide a 'good enough' solution that doesn't sacrifice readability. I have to go now, but there is a good discussion about this in the book "High Performance Python"

Comment: @CharlesAddis I've accepted your answer since it provides the best compromise between readability and speed. The lists of strings of come from csv files of varying length. Usually in the range of 50 000 - 100 000, and the number of files is anywhere from 2-100. That step took ~300 sec (with my original code), for files on the smaller side (~30k line files, 18 files). So your solution should work reasonably well for files up to the higher-end limit.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that converting it to C could give you [orders of magnitude](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/compare.php?lang=python3&lang2=gcc) increases in speed. You may be able to get some significant optimizations just by using Cython.

As an aside, for one of my senior projects, converting our graph manipulation from Python to C yielded a processing time ~6 orders of magnitude smaller because in C you can [bit twiddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation) much more effectively and without all the overhead. (>30 hours vs <1 second per pass).

Comment: @TemporalWolf exactly this. If performance is a constraint, python may not be the best implementation language. Perhaps write a service in C that the python code can call (to avoid porting your whole app to C).

Comment: @TemporalWolf thanks for the very informative link - it also contains bioinformatics examples too which are quite appealing since that's what I work with.

Answer (score 1):

This should be faster:

```
def _insert_aa(string, index, aa):
    return string[0:index] + aa + string[index+1:]
```

EDIT: You can slice the head and tail only once and reuse like this:

```
def generate_all_variants(string, replacements):
    for i in range(len(string)):
        head = string[:i]
        tail = string[i+1:]
        for letter in replacements:
            yield head + letter + tail

for variant in generate_all_variants("abcd",  ['1', '2', '3']):
    print(variant)
```

Comment: `"".join` is always faster then concatenating using `+`

Comment: Your edit seems to be the solution I'm looking for. Still, why sticking to the `+` instead of `"".join`?

Comment: The join function takes a single argument, often a list, but it takes time to create the list.

Comment: @Carlo `"".join` is **not** _always_ faster. On short strings, particularly those with a length of less than 10, it's often slower because of the incurred overhead.